# My female 1 year old cat won't stop meowing at night

Tags: cats, communication, separation-anxiety

My female cat, Apollo, is a little over a year old, and at night she meows a lot. Some high-pitched and some lower-pitched. Sometimes she stares at the corner of my room and sometimes she meows while walking around. I've done a lot of research and I'm not sure if she's bored or lonely. She has her brother and tons of things to enrich her. But she still does it. I've asked my mom who’s a veterinarian, but she's not 100% sure what it is. Is it anxiety? Boredom?

She doesn't sound like she's in pain but I don't know if she's seeing things or what. So I thought I'd ask and see if anyone could give me advice on what to do.